How are NanoLED and MicroLED computer screens designed differently?
How are NanoLED and MicroLED computer screens designed differently?

The NanoLED trademark seems to indicate that the issue is probably marketing, and not different engineering or materials: 


I don't see a difference since both are allegedly self-emmissive and turn electricity into light
Other than the different emmiter name, I can't see anything different.



I think the difference between these 2 tecnologies is in the design (circuit design too since panels are a circuit of LEDs) as suggested by Mokubai when they said

just look closely at the image. You can clearly see the difference
just by looking at the LED stages. One has single colour elements, the
other shows a lot of little dots.

I don't understand what this means (Microled having single colour elements while Nanoled has a lot of little dots).
Demis said that

The answer is: the NanoLED is utilizing electrically pumped quantum
dots - electrical current directly energizes the quantum dots. This is
higher efficiency than a backlight optically energizing the quantum
dots. From flatpanelshd.com "Todays displays that use quantum dots in
some form are so-called photoluminescent meaning that the QDs absorb
light and convert it (for example blue light converted into red or
green, as in QD-OLED) whereas electroluminescent quantum dots convert
electricity into light, no separate light emitting diodes
required."

I am not sure I understand that either, whether the answer could be reduced to just

MicroLED uses photoluminescent quantum dots while NanoLED uses
electroluminescent quantum dots.

If that is so the question swifts from NanoLED and MicroLED to Electroluminescence and Photoluminescence (and the QDs that use them).
What is the difference between Electroluminescence and Photoluminescence and how are the Quantum Dots that use these physical phenomena designed differently?

The term NanoLED appears to be a marketing term, not a technical term, don't let it confuse you.

MicroLED is just a regular LED, but really small (down to few-micron sizes) - so that is more of a technical term. Like a regular LED chip, a MicroLED converts electricity to photons - I think you can call that Electroluminescence.
A NanoLED, being NOT a technical term, appears to use an LED/MicroLED underneath a Quantum Dot solution/ink. The Quantum Dot is photolumienscent (photons → photons), but the "NanoLED" is a combo like: Electrons →  LED → photons → Quantum Dots → photons.

Quantum dots are small nano particles that absorb one wavelength/color or light and emit another. For example they are often shown in solution like this from here:

Where an off-camera light is illuminating/energizing the QD’s, and the QD’s in the vials (suspended in liquid) emit different colors depending on the size of the QD nano particles. They are photoluminescent, meaning photons → QD → photons.
For this "NanoLED" (meaning MicroLED → QD) display, the key takeaway is QD's need an input light source first, and the different types of QD’s then convert that to a different color (Red/Green/Blue).  Any time you have a conversion like this, you always lose some energy - not every input photon gets converted to the desired output color.
Thus the QD's need to a backlight or polarizing blockers for each pixel or some other electrical Mechanism for turning each pixel on and off. The QD by itself can’t usually be electrically controlled. Here is an example from Applied Materials that explains how the QD layers are ink-jet printed on top of microLED’s, and you need specific microLED colors to excite specific QD colors.
The MicroLED on the other hand takes in electricity, and converts that directly to light. So you have direct electrical control of the light source with no optical→optical conversion. If you make 3 different colored LED’s, and make them small enough that you get high enough pixel density, then you have a competitive display technology with fewer components to assemble (you can remove the layer of QD’s). However you need to place each MicroLED automatically - this may have been too slow and difficult/costly until some companies developed very fast pick-and-place / transfer processes.

Didn't you say that MicroLEDs were photoluminescent as opposed to the electroluminescent NanoLEDs? If they converted one color of light to another (as I understand photoluminescence) how would that be self-emmissive? If MicroLEDS take in electricity and convert it directly into light how does Photoluminescence come into play in MicroLEDs? What about NanoLEDs what is the difference?

FYI the term NanoLED is a marketing term, not a technical term, don't let it confuse you.  "MicroLED" is just a regular LED, but really small (down to few-micron sizes) - so that is more of a technical term.  Like a regular LED chip, a MicroLED converts electricity to photons - I think you can call that Electroluminescence.  A "NanoLED", being NOT a technical term, appears to use an LED/MicroLED underneath a Quantum Dot solution/ink. The Quantum Dot is photolumienscent (photons → photons), but the "NanoLED" is a combo like: Electrons →  LED → photons → QD → photons.

Also please accept the answer if it answered your question!

I copied this add'l info into the answer.

Then I am confused because you said earlier in the Meta that "the NanoLED is utilizing electrically pumped quantum dots. This is higher efficiency than a backlight optically energizing the quantum dots." I am confused by the contradiction. Are Microleds photoluminescent or electroluminescent (because what you said in the meta and what you are saying now are opposites). How can something exhibit photoluminescence as opposed to electroluminescence and still be self-emitting?

Just read the above answer. It is better written.

I have already read it. But it is still confusing the Picture I found calls NanoledTM Electroluminescent Quantum Dot Display.

I find it difficult to believe a text with second thoughts and reservations. If the answer (the difference between Microled and Nanoled) was in fact that Nanoled is a marketing term not a technical term the answer could use more definitive wording and be short (less than 120-150 words) and resolute not "appears to be". I am earnestly confused because not only your comment in the Meta said that Nanoled was Electroluminescent but the image says NanoledTM  Electroluminescent Quantum Dot Display (how could something Photoluminescent a quantum dot optically energized by backlight be self emissive)?

You seem to be getting stuck on a definition that I think you should throw out. If you won’t believe someone who’s entire career has been in photonics and electro-optics, then I’m not sure where you’ll find an answer that satisfies you. I would suggest to ignore this “self-emissive” concept. Again, please ignore the other thread that was a “comment” not an answer.

When you word it like "appears to be" instead of "is" I read right there in the text second thoughts. I am not sure after reading it that you know what Nanoled "are" (I for sure don't know but that is why I asked in the first place.). Second thought and hesitance create doubt in me.
